# Mesh wont move with bones in pose mode

Tags: animation, bones

I am having the problem that the mesh won't move when I move the bones in pose mode.
I did the following:

started with one bone at the bottom and extruded the others upwards.

Then I made sure all bones were correctly positioned within the mesh.

I then selected all and applied all transforms

Then I selected the mesh and shift selected the armature and did ctrl p to parent with automatic weights.

When I switch to pose mode I can move and rotate the bones - however, the mesh stays in place.

What am I missing?

[image: Mes with amature]

[image: scene hirachy]

Comment: Check if after parenting with automatic weights a yellow error message appears at the bottom of the 3D window.

Comment: no error message

Comment: add the blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: make sure that the Deform option of your bones is activated, if it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: thanks for the advice - i'll fix the topology and come back if the problem still exists